# How to add images based on a counter?

Tags: html

I would like to create a webpage that gets external information, and display the count number in number of images. For example: if it gets 10 it will display 10 cups of water.
What will be the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Shai.

Comment: for (i=1; i <=n; i++)
document.write('<img src="blabla"/>');  n is in your example 10.

Comment: thanks Hasan. How can i loop in html? it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: you look in JavaScript not HTML, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to @HasanTahsin's answer, using jQuery (It's easier than pure javascript):

```
// Add jQuery
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

// Your script for adding images
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        for (i=1; i <=n; i++) $(<selector to add html>).append('<img src="blabla"/>');
    });
</script>
```

n is in your example 10.

For external information you will need some server side client (PHP, python, etc) to do the select for you. You can call this via ajax,again using jQuery it's as easy as [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Here is an [example](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107).

Comment: i mean that if i handle an external database, i want the numbers in that table to influence the number of images appear on the visitor's screen (so they won't need to read numbers...).

Comment: for that you will need some server side client (PHP, python, etc) to do the select for you and you can call this via ajax, again using jQuery it's as easy as [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: more details in my answer above.